# vb.net imports does not contain any public member

Tags: vb.net, reference, import

I have a working and buildling Sln with multiple projects all in VB.net. They are in a virtual PC running XP and Visual Studio 2010.  It builds and runs fine.  I copy the files to my windows 8 pc with VS2010 SP1 and VS 2012.  Several of the projects reference a helper project. Initially they referenced the dll from the project. I changed it to the actual project reference to remove any dll issues.

Now in my windows 8 pc every Import or code reference to the helper project is failing.  The helper project is building fine.  I cannot figure out why the imports are failing as it works fine in the XP machine and none of the references are erroring on the windows 8 pc.

If I unload the referenced helper project it builds and runs fine on windows 8. I clean the entire solution and I deleted every dll the the helper project created.  I am positive the helper project is creating a new dll and being used by the other projects. So.. why does it work if I unload the project. It should be the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to recreate the sln file after that it worked in win 8